# My first PATCH install

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, installation

I've got the message from magento to install a Patch.
So I downloaded it and uploaded it to my root.

Created a `patch.php` containing:

```
<?php
    print("<PRE>");
    passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-38-41.sh");
    print("</PRE>");
    echo "Done";
?>
```

Uploaded it and gave me the following after I ran `patch.php`

```
Warning:  passthru() has been disabled for security reasons in
          /home/xxx/public_html/webshop/patch.php on line 3

Done
```

Not sure what's next. Am I done now or do I need to find another solution?

----------- UPDATE
After contacting my hosting provider they enabled the `passthru()` function.
Now it's working:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
Done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `shell_exec` or `exec` but my guess is that those will be disabled as well.

That leaves you with 2 options.

1. Ask your hosting company to apply the patch using SSH
2. Run the patch on your local machine, see what files are changed* and upload those files to the remote server

** open the patch file in a text editor and check the files it touches. The file changed by the patch would be indicated by something like `diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php`*

Comment: Thnx but, Option 1: I don't think they will do this everytime there is an update. Option 2: There are over 60 files changed. The risk to make a mistake is to big. Is it uncommon to ask my hosting provider to enable `passthru()`? I need to do this, probably, on a regular basis.

Comment: it's disabled to prevent malicious scripts messing up your server, I'm guessing they're not gonna enable that. I would suggest either finding a better hosting provider (this one sounds a bit cheap) or using option 2 :)

Comment: I have just send them an email where I ask them to enable it and provide me with another option if they don't. See where that leads me...

Comment: good luck with that! If they come up with a better solution please do add it as answer here. I'm sure a lot of people will find it useful

Comment: I will. They usually are willing to make changes or provide solutions

Comment: See my updated version

Comment: @Interactive great! Glad to could help you

Comment: wellll..... :-) I did run the patch and if I do it again it skips parts because they are allready updated. But if I update my cache and logout/in, magento still hits me with the patch.

Comment: You mean the notification in the admin backend?

Comment: Yes it still pops up

Comment: Ahh ignore that, should go away after a while. I'm not even sure it really checks if you patched

Comment: LOL.... Thnx for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can install patch CLI if you have SSH access to the server , just uplaod the file via FTP and run **./filename.sh** to install the patch

Comment: My hostingprovider enabled the `passthru()` function but I'll take a look at this also. Thnx!